# Why is outlook stretching out my images height?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

This week I was introduced to the wonder that is html emails. I have an email that needs to display an image and some text side by side. The problem that I'm coming up against is that the image is getting stretched vertically instead of the height being auto set by the width. 
This problem only happens in outlook.

This is what is being rendered:
[image]

and this is the code that makes it up:

```
<table class="container" align="center" width="640" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="256" style="width:40%; float:left; text-align:right;">
      <img class="max-image" width="256" style="display:block;width:100%; height:auto;" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/25/17/56/people-821624_1280.jpg" alt="coach picture"/>
    </td>
    <td width="384" style="width:60%; float:left; text-align:center;">
      <table width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="10"></td>
          <td>
            <div style="padding-left: 10px;text-align: center;">
              <p style="color:#6AA342;"><strong>Meet The Coach</strong></p>
              <p>{{ coach_first_name }}</p>
              <p>{{ bio }}</p>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From what I've gathered online so far, outlook doesn't seem to like when you don't explicitly set the height property of the image, but the issue I have is that this image is dynamically set and it may be a different aspect ratio from email to email, so I can't really set the height of the image.

Comment: Hi there, I can't seem to replicate the issue in any Outlook program or the web based Outlook. That doesn't mean you don't have an issue but it may mean you have a wider issue with your code. Are you able to post your entire code? As well as that, can you confirm which Outlook client you are seeing this issue in?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the following line:

```
<td width="256" style="width:40%; float:left; text-align:right;">
```

You may see the `float:left` property which is not supported in Outlook. The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML bodies.

You can find the full list supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Comment: While this answer is helpful, it does not fix the issue at hand, so should be added as a comment.

Comment: Let's wait for the poster to check whether it helps or not.

Comment: There are other elements that are not supported in Outlook, so it would be great to evaluate the markup first.